# Calculate radius of circle required to completely overlap rectangle when centered within it

Tags: geometry, circles, rectangles

Consider a rectangle with known width ($w$), height ($h$) and center ($R$). You can assume $w\geqslant h$.

A random point ($C$) is selected *within* the rectangle which is a distance of $x$ (horizontally) and $y$ (vertically) from $R$:

[image: Image 1]

A circle is drawn centered at $C$ such that it completely overlaps the rectangle, but no more:

[image: Image 2]

Is there a way to calculate the circle's radius $r$, given the known inputs $w$, $h$, $R$, $C$, $x$ and $y$?

Comment: Yes.  The radius is simply the maximum distance of the rectangle's four corners to $C$.  If all four corners are in the circle, then the entire rectangle is covered by the circle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is. The radius of the circle is merely the length from $C$ to the vertex of the rectangle farthest away. Just draw a line from $C$ to this vertex and make that the hypotenuse of a right triangle. The legs of the triangle would be $|y|+\frac{h}2$, and $|x|+\frac{w}2$. Using the Pythagorean Theorem, this is $$\sqrt{({|y|+\frac{h}2})^2+({|x|+\frac{w}2})^2}$$.

Comment: Yes, though I would add the proviso that $x, y \geq 0$, without loss of generality, or replace them by $|x|$ and $|y|$, respectively.

Comment: @BrianTung Good catch. I will update my answer.

Comment: Oh yes, so it is! Thank you very much

Comment: Can't believe I didn't spot this while working on those diagrams haha